# Calendar view in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible in calendar view in odoo 9 display all item where is status = complete, other item where status (new, in progress) I don't need in calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show some records in any view : tree,form ....
you need to provide the domain in you WindowAction record in the XML fiel:

```xml
<record .. model="ir.actions.act_window">
    ....
    ...
    <!-- this is for testing only if it return all record 
         then this doesn't work else you domain is wrong -->
    <field name="domain">[('id','=','False)]</field>
  </record>
```

Comment: Tnx for help, but after add above line again return all items.

Comment: try to do the same domain on your action if the records still shown then the domain is not working else you are not putting the right domain

Comment: good i had this problem with cache ones it make go grazy before realizing that it's because of it lol